# Which stackage snapshot does stack install use?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Trying to run

```
stack install git-mediate
```

(per [`git-mediate`'s instructions](https://github.com/Peaker/git-mediate))

I get an error message regarding dependent package versions:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for git-mediate-1.0.8:
    Diff-0.3.4 from stack configuration does not match >=0.4  (latest matching version is 0.4.0)
needed since git-mediate is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' in /Users/yairchu/.stack/config.yaml to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/yairchu/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml:

- Diff-0.4.0@sha256:b5cfbeed498f555a18774ffd549bbeff7a24bdfe5984154dcfc9f4328a3c2847,1275

Plan construction failed.
```

It's odd that the stack configuration has `Diff-0.3.4`, as currently both LTS and nightly stackage snapshots [currently contain `Diff-0.4.0`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-16.18/package/Diff-0.4.0) (`lts-16.8` and `nightly-2020-10-13`).

What is this stack configuration thing and why is it pinned to old versions of libraries?

Comment: There's a bit of documentation on `stack`'s "global project" at https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#finding-project-configs-and-the-implicit-global-project. You can edit the snapshot used in the "global project" in `/Users/yairchu/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`.

Comment: @sjakobi thanks! that explains where the resolver comes from. Do you want to turn your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack install` is an alias for `stack build --copy-bins`, so it's really just `stack build` plus the additional step of copying the built executables to `~/.local/bin`.

So, the real question is "how does `stack build` decide what resolver to use?"  Well, if you provide it on the command line, it uses that one, as in:

```
stack install --resolver lts-16.18 git-mediate
```

If you don't give an explicit resolver, the default depends on where the build command is run.  If you run it inside a stack project, it'll default to the resolver specified in the project's `stack.yaml` file.  For example:

```
stack new --resolver lts-16.0 exampleproject  # create project with lts-16.0 resolver
cd exampleproject
stack build git-mediate   # this will build git-mediate using lts-16.0
```

If you build it outside of any project, then it uses the global project setting, which will be whatever `resolver` is set in `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`, as mentioned in the comments / other answer.

Note that the `stack install` alias will always copy the executable into the "global" `~/.local/bin`, regardless of where it was built.  So, if you run `stack install git-mediate` in the `exampleproject` directory, as above, you'll get the version built with `lts-16.0` as the globally installed version.

Soooo...  be careful where you run `stack install`!

Note that, with respect to `git-mediate` specfically, there was recently a buggy version published to Stackage, as documented [here](https://github.com/Peaker/git-mediate/issues/26).  The error message is slightly different than the one you got, but the underlying problem might have been the same.  So, it's possible that just running `stack update` without having to modify the resolver setting would work to fix your build problem, if you haven't already fixed it.

Comment: I'm well aware of the recent problem with git-mediate - I asked this question in my process of fixing the very same problem :)

Comment: HA!  I didn't spot the connection.  Well, the note may be helpful if someone else searching for this bug stumbles across this question.

Answer (score 1):

`stack` is implicitly using it's ["global project"](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#finding-project-configs-and-the-implicit-global-project) defined in `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`. To control the stackage snapshot being used this file can be edited (or just deleted to use the latest LTS)